# How to get all unique values in a cell array of matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, cell-array

I want to get all unique values in `A`, where `A` is a cell array of matrices of different shapes and sizes:

```
A = {[], 1, [2 3], [4 5; 6 7]};
U = [];
for ii = 1: numel(A)
    a = A{ii};
    U = [U; a(:)];
end
U = unique(U);
```

That returns:

```
U =
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7
```

If all elements in `A` where row vectors, I could use `[A{:}]` like:

```
U = unique([A{1:3}]);
```

That returns:

```
U =
 1     2     3
```

But in my case it throws an exception:

> Error using horzcat
>
> Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not
> consistent.

So how can I avoid that for-loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cellfun` to reshape all elements in the cell.

```
U = unique(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)reshape(x,1,numel(x)),A, 'UniformOutput', false)));
```

or avoiding the `reshape`with

```
U = unique(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)x(:).',A, 'UniformOutput', false)));
```

Answer (score 3):

We can go this way:

```
A = {[], 1, [2 3], [2 0; 4 5; 6 7]};
AA = cellfun( @(x) unique(x(:)), A, 'UniformOutput' , false)
res = unique(cat(1, AA{:}))
```

1. First of all create unique array for each cell - it let us avoid converting all the cells to numeric just only unique values.
2. Lets convert cell array to one numeric array - `cat(1, AA{:})` .
3. Find unique values through this resulting array.